# columns missing from last dataset after merge in R

Tags: r, merge

I have merged two datasets but the last three columns of whichever dataset I merge seem not to show in the final dataset.
I use the merge function:

```
AllData <- merge(NonLing.df,AJT.df, by="child_id")
AllData.df <- as.data.frame(AllData)
```

before that I have transformed the reaction times into logarithmic values for each dataset, and since the new column is added as the last one of the data set, the `AllData.df` does not contain the log value of whichever dataset is set as the second one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I cannot see exactly where the problem is without a reprex. I would recommend to rather use the join function of dplyr: left_join(NonLing.df,AJT.df, by="child_id")

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. i tired using left_join, but still, three columsn form the second table are missing.

Merged <- left_join(NonLing.df,AJT.df, by="child_id")
Merged.df <- as.data.frame(Merged)

one of these columns is the log transformation for the reaction times of a column, so I tried running it again on the Merged.df, but I get an error

Merged.df$log.RT <- log(AllData.df$response_time_AJT)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, log.RT, value = c(9.95008483791291, : replacement has 65049 rows, data has 64560

Comment: This would be better if you included a reproducible dataset. Examples are given here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn6BgT15yIs&ab_channel=CradleToGraveR

Answer (score 0):

for the next time: it helps if you add some example data for your dataframes and a example for expected outcome.
Based on your code, you probably just need to add the `all=TRUE` to your `merge`:

```
AllData <- merge(NonLing.df,AJT.df, by="child_id", all = TRUE)
AllData.df <- as.data.frame(AllData)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the result is still the same: the last three columns are missing. Criaciall I am missimg the log column which I did in each table before merging them: 
AJT.df$log.RT_AJT <- log(AJT.df$response_time_AJT)
NonLing.df$log.RT_NL <- log(NonLing.df$response_time_NL)

so i tried doing it again on the merged dataset
AllData.df$log.RT <- log(AllData.df$response_time_AJT)

the columns is still not there, and there is no error message (like in the case with the left_join merge - see above)